# Read-only FS: Need to create virtual file

Tags: python, python-2.7, filesystems, aws-lambda

I have a Python app running on AWS Lambda, which has a read-only FS. During the initialization of the app, I need to copy a file and rename it depending on a few factors.

I'm getting this error right now: `IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'file_gen.txt'`

Is there a way I can make a link to a virtual file sitting in RAM or something to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda only lets you write to the /tmp directory.  Try to save your file there.  According to the [AWS Limits Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) you can write up to 512MB.

Comment: Unfortunately, the library I'm using is looking for a specific file in the local directory. I ended up submitting a PR for the project to allow custom file names.